# failing on specify user permissions php session

Tags: php

in my code I have user profile, and every user has his own profile, but when I try to make a function that gives permission to the current user session for example edit his page only, it takes effect on all the users, and i can specify it only to his profile, any ideas how to make it work?

my basic code goes like this

```
//check if the user is the account owner!
$mypage= "no";
if($_SESSION['user']){ //maybe need to be compared to something? 
    echo 'thats your page';//basic test to see if it works, but it works for every user's pafe
    $mypage = "yes";
}
```

thanks for helpers!

Comment: Its basic login logout function in core php, if you google it you will get lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

The page will need to have a unique identifier, for example the page might be:

```
user.php?id=5
```

Then, you can add that to your if check to make sure the currently logged in user is looking at this page:

```
if($_SESSION['user'] && $_SESSION['user_id'] == $_GET['id'])
```

I'm not sure what you have stored in $_SESSION['user'] but you get the idea hopefully. Ideally in PHP you shoud generally use strict comparisons (=== instead of ==) but that's beyond the scope of the question really.